# Rearrange columns in Excel SQL Transorm/Pivot

Tags: sql, excel

I am using excel vba in order to perform an in-sheet query, including a transform/pivot command. Please see below for a simplified version.

```
Transform First([Description])
Select [ID],[Sale Status]
From [Data$]
Group by [ID],[Sale Status]
Pivot TimePeriod in ([2015],[2016],[2017])
```

The first example is working pretty well, doing what I want. The only issue I have is that I'd like to put the Time Period columns between the ID and the Sale Status, per request by the client. I can probably just do another select statement outside of the transform, but I don't want to add extra crunch time if it can be avoided. I have tried things like this, but it threw errors.

```
Transform First([Description])
Select [ID],[2015],[2016],[2017],[Sale Status]
From [Data$]
Group by [ID],[Sale Status]
Pivot TimePeriod in ([2015],[2016],[2017])
```

Does anyone know if this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems dodgy as it appears you want/need to select values of a column as column headings as opposed to columns themselves;

I'm thinking you'd be better off with a select statement which gets the data you want included in the pivot, then putting this data into a worksheet, and building the pivot table manually in a second worksheet.

This doesn't seem much of an answer, but I'm having trouble envisaging what the data may look like; If you can provide an example of the data, I might be able to make more of a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using conditional aggregation in place of the transform query since arrangement of columns cannot work as you intend using the crosstab. As an aside, this is typically the way to pivot data in SQL as `TRANSFORM` is strictly a Jet/ACE SQL specific method.

```sql
SELECT [ID], First(IIF(TimePeriod = 2015, [Description], NULL)) As [2015], 
             First(IIF(TimePeriod = 2016, [Description], NULL)) As [2016],
             First(IIF(TimePeriod = 2017, [Description], NULL)) As [2017], 
       [Sales Status]
FROM [Data$]
GROUP BY [ID], [Sale Status]
```